# MSBuild Iterate Properties

Tags: msbuild

Is it possible to pass MSBuild some command line properties:

```
msbuild.exe /p:Configuration=Release;labDeploy=false;prodDeploy=true
```

Then somehow iterate through the key/value pairs passed in via the properties arg.

If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what you want to use them for, but if you're trying to use them for execution control, look at [MSBuild Conditions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7szfhaft.aspx). For example, my company's "product" at this point, fully implemented, consists of a traditional client-server app, a web-based reporting app, and a newer Silverlight implementation of some of the client-server application.

In my master MSBuild project file, I have separate targets for each application,  Whether or not they run is controlled by a Condition check of a few command-line parameters.

```
  <!-- run the builds for the selected build types -->
  <Target Name="RunBuild" DependsOnTargets="ValidateBuildSelected">
    <CallTarget Targets="BuildWindowsClientApp" Condition="'$(BuildWindowsClientApp)'=='TRUE'" />
    <CallTarget Targets="BuildWebReportingApp" Condition="'$(BuildWebReportingApp)'=='TRUE'" />
    <CallTarget Targets="BuildWebClientApp" Condition="'$(BuildWebClientApp)'=='TRUE'" />
  </Target>
```

I can run one or all of the options based on how I set the parameter string up.